# Player attributes after starting a match

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Say I have these two attributes-

```
#define Role_1 0xFFFF0000
#define Role_2 0x0000FFFF
```

I would like to know how can I access the attribute of a specific player after a match has been started. Or more accurate, how can I get the attribute of a specific player from the method

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match ?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the roles this way. From [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html):

> Player attributes have some limitations:
>
> Only one player can fill each role. Your game defines a complete set
> of roles; all roles defined by your game must be filled. Each match
> request can only request a single role. Roles are checked only for
> auto-matched players. If the player invites friends to join the match,
> friends do not get to pick a role. Roles are not displayed in the
> standard user interface for matchmaking provided by Game Kit. Your
> application must provide its own custom user interface to allow
> players to choose a role. **The match object returned to your
> application does not tell you which roles the players selected. Your
> game must send the role-selection information separately after the
> match is created.**

It looks like you will have to do it yourself. I would try this method: `sendDataToAllPlayers:withDataMode:error:`
for sending
and this one: `match:didReceiveData:fromPlayer:` for receiving the data.